# passing encrypred password from android to web service to mysql database using ksoap2

Tags: android, mysql, database, encryption, android-ksoap2

I'm sending username and password from android app to web service using skoap2, web service connects to MySQL database. it works perfect with password as text, but if I send an encrypted password, I got illegalCharacterException when creating SoapEnvelope. I think I got the idea what is the problem, but I have no idea how can I solve it. in what form (now String) should I pass the encrypted password and how to store it in the database? (will varchar cause same error)?

```
String password = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.passwordr1)).getText().toString();
MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256"); //$NON-NLS-1$
messageDigest.update(password.getBytes());
String encryptedPassword = new String(messageDigest.digest());
```

later in the code

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
```

...

```
PropertyInfo passwordProp =new PropertyInfo();
passwordProp.setName("password");
passwordProp.setValue(params[1]);
passwordProp.setType(String.class);
request.addProperty(passwordProp);
```

...

```
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);       
HttpTransportSE ht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
ht.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
String response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse().toString();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is example how to send byte[]
https://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/issues/detail?id=116